# Bootstrap popover arrow correction when rounded corners are removed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have setup a Bootstrap 3 popover design [here](http://www.bootply.com/3oMRwFiqxn).

I have removed the border-radius with this code:

```
.popover {
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This resulted in the arrow disappearing from view. I want to retain the arrow. Tried a lot of solutions offered here but couldn't get it right. How can I correct my code?

Comment: Could you be more precise please, with witch browser are you testing? I cant see the arrow at all with chrome.

Comment: You see, I have removed the border-radius in the csss window. That's the reason you are not seeing the arrow. My question is, how can I make the arrow reappear in this setup?

Comment: there's no 'arrow' (whatever it is) in the code, so how can it reappear?

Comment: The popover component of Bootstrap has an arrow by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the overflow causing the issue. If you want to set the custom height do that on `.popover-content`

See here: http://www.bootply.com/esSpOuWbLb

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is not because of removing rounded corners.**

Due to the **overflow-y:auto;** You getting this issue

```
.popover {
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Solution:

```
.popover {
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    max-height: 50%;
}
.popover-content{
  height: 80px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```